# Extended AWS MS SQL RDS DB audit file search with a server timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services

I am getting MS SQL RDS DB audit search with following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.rds_fn_get_audit_file('D:\rdsdbdata\SQLAudit\*.sqlaudit', default, default)
```

Timestamp is coming in event_time column and it is in UTC, however, I need to convert it to the querying server timezone. Is it possible to extend this search with extra column with recalculated timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has less to do with AWS or even SQL Audit and more "how do I convert UTC time to local time?". This should get you there:

```sql
SELECT *,
   [event_time_local] = SWITCHOFFSET(event_time, DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))
FROM msdb.dbo.rds_fn_get_audit_file('D:\rdsdbdata\SQLAudit\*.sqlaudit', default, default);
```

This will convert the `event_time` column into whatever timezone the SQL Server is in. If you need it to be a different timezone than that, you're welcome to provide a different offset to the `SWITCHOFFSET()` function.